# help with grammar!

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Ever since scientists discovered that the fingerprints of each person on earth was unique, fingerprinting has played an important role in law enforcement.

Is the usage of was correct in this sentence,or should it be is/are?

Comment: Either is acceptable. As with reported speech, it depends on where you want to put the emphasis—the facts at the time or the facts that continue to be true.

Comment: It's all wrong. *Fingerprints* is plural.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want this sentence as a printed content or in verbal usage, we can rephrase it as below:

Print use:
Ever since that it was discovered that fingerprints are unique for each person on Planet Earth, fingerprinting has played an important role in law enforcement.

Verbal use:
Fingerprinting has played a crucial role in law enforcement. Especially, ever since that it was discovered that the fingerprints are unique for each person.

Apart from Grammatical correction or going by the rule-book, see if you can rephrase the content according to need and usage.

Comment: You've only indirectly answered the actual question. And your answer is: "Use the present tense."